# What is the difference between the old ListView and new CollectionView in Xamarin 4?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I don't understand what is different in Xamarin Form by new version 4.0 between old ListView and new CollectionView. Why is better to use CollectionView?

I se help in microsoft docs, but don't se anything better.

`public CollectionView ();`

Comment: I had the same question and found this article helpful: https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2019/07/lets-play-with-collectionview-layouts.html. One big difference is performance, but it also allows horizontal scrolling and multi column or multi row formats.

Comment: FWIW: @PeriHartman - *"One big difference is performance,"* - I see NO evidence in that linked article that CollectionView has better performance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The CollectionView is a flexible and performant view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications.

BUT
The ListView is an ItemsView that displays a collection of data as a vertical list.

Conclusion: if you want to display things vertically use ListView, if you want do display things with your own style use CollectionView

Comment: ListView is more dependent on the underlying platform's implementation of scrolling lists. Sometimes that is a good thing, but sometimes it isn't: If you encounter a glitch you can't fix, try CollectionView. Which one gives smoother scrolling depends on your item layout - I don't know any overall answer to when to use one or the other (for vertical lists).

Comment: Calling CollectionView "performant" requires an _extremely_ liberal definition of that word...

Answer (score 2):

ListView->
Android: Listview->
Ios:     TableView

CollectionView->
Android: RecyclerView->
Ios:     UITableView

In other words collectionview is better than listview. In all ways.

Comment: Maybe CollectionView is better than ListView, but your answer does not tell you how you came to that conclusion. Why is an Android RecyclerView better than an Android ListView and why is an iOS UITableView better than an iOS TableView?

Comment: what about the janks? Xamarin Collectionview is worst than using webview apps (like ionic)

Answer (score -1):

[ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) is a view for presenting lists of data, especially long lists that require scrolling.
The [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) is a flexible and performant view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications.

[CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) is a view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications. It aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview?view=xamarin-forms). For more information, see [Xamarin.Forms CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/).

Comment: its definitely not performant in any way!