# Is collectionview the new way instead of listview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to ask a general question. I read that `CollectionView` is more flexible and has better performance than `ListiView`.

So is `CollectionView` the new way to go? Should I replace all my `ListiView` to `CollectionView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction)

> CollectionView is a view for presenting lists of data using different
> layout specifications. It aims to provide a more flexible, and
> performant alternative to ListView.

you do not necessarily need to replace existing `ListView`, but you should generally choose `CollectionView` for any new development

Comment: Note that if you are targeting a non iOS/Android/UWP platform like macOS or WPF, CollectionView will likely remain unimplemented.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to replace it everywhere depending on the use case:

They have some similarities and some differences also, interesting Microsoft documentation : [collectionview-and-listview-differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction#collectionview-and-listview-differences)

Be aware that `CollectionView` is relatively new and may still bring it own issues for now, but it is the way to go for the future especially regarding performance.

> It aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to ListView.

Related question:
[What is the difference between the old ListView and new CollectionView in Xamarin 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56268458/what-is-the-difference-between-the-old-listview-and-new-collectionview-in-xamari)

Comment: It seems to me like ListView and recyclerView in Android. RecyclerView was better in all ways.

Comment: I didn't used `RecyclerView` so I can't tell, but I don't think they are going to make ListView obsolete quickly.